# Looking for Example Project Using MonoTouch Calling a Json Web endpoint

Tags: xamarin.ios, webclient, json.net, restsharp

I'm new to MonoTouch and have been wrestling with trying to POST to a web site that will return JSON to me.  In the MonoTouch example site,there are examples cut and pasted but no working projects I could find.  RestSharp looks pretty nice but I have been unable to find any IOS projects that include a working example.  I know it should be easy, just cut and paste the code, System.dll has the System.Net name spaces, but for me I keep getting unresolved references.  A working example I could run would go a long way.  Even just a trivial example.  I can add all my own complicated stuff.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you post the code you're using and the errors you're getting?  Then we can help you with that specific problem.  Generally speaking, doing a simple POST using HttpWebRequest or WebClient should work the same way it does in a normal .NET project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a snippet from my code I've used with the System.JSON namespace:

```
public JsonValue Post(string address) {

    JsonValue value = null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        req.Method = "POST";

        JsonObject postJson = new JsonObject();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in this.FormParams) 
            postJson.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(val.Key, new JsonPrimitive(val.Value)));

        byte[] postData = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postJson.ToString());

        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) 
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (resp.GetResponseStream ())) 
            {
                value = JsonValue.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _lastError = ex.Message;
        Log.Error(String.Format("Exception on JsonHandler::Post(action): {0}", ex.Message)); 
    }
    return value;
}
```

where 'action' is the address to access, like http://service-address.com/json/users
And 'this.FormParams'  is a list containing the post-data.
It will return a JsonValue which can contain all kind of JSON objects.